# laravel livewire select box not working. how can i fix it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am making a very simple select box using livewire. This is trying to use wire:model but it doesn't work.

livewire file is

```php
public $city = 'Seoul';

public function mount(){}

public function render()
{
     echo 'city : '.$this->city;

     return view('livewire.weather', []);
}
```

and blade file is

```html
<select class="form-control" wire:model="city" name="city">
   <option value="Seoul">서울</option>
   <option value="Busan">부산</option>
   <option value="Daejeon">대전</option>
   <option value="Daegu">대구</option>
   <option value="Kwangju">광주</option>
   <option value="Incheon">인천</option>
   <option value="Suwon">수원</option>
   <option value="Changwon">창원</option>
   <option value="Ulsan">울산</option>
   <option value="Andong">안동</option>
   <option value="Chuncheon">춘천</option>
   <option value="Cheongju">청주</option>
   <option value="Jeonju">전주</option>
   <option value="Jeju">제주</option>
</select>
```

How to connect livewire and select box in html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what is your problem here. Check network tab - `$city` should be updated after selecting

```
public $city = 'Seoul';

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.weather');
}
```